# firebase document update trigger function error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to stream insert the data into the Bigquery table and have the below issues with function. Not sure where is an error in the code. I have followed this to achieve with realtime data.
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/main/samples/insertRowsAsStream.js

> Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const {BigQuery} = require("@google-cloud/bigquery");

exports.onWriteTrigger = functions
    .firestore
    .document("leaseCompany/{documentId}")
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
    /*
    onCreate: google.firestore.document.create
    onUpdate: google.firestore.document.update
    onDelete: google.firestore.document.delete
    */ 
      const row = {
        // insertId: document.data.id,
        // json: {
        timestamp: context.timestamp,
        name: change.after.data().name,
        // documentName: context.resource.name,
        documentId: change.after.id,
        eventId: context.eventId,
        data: change.after.data().country,
      };
    
      // console.log(insertRows);
      async function insertBigQuery(rows) {
    try {
      console.log(row);
      const datasetName = "firestore_export";
      const tableName = "leaseCompany";
      const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery();
      const ds = bigqueryClient.dataset(datasetName);
      const tbl = ds.table(tableName);
      await tbl.insert(rows)
          .then((data) => {
            return true;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            // An API error or partial failure occurred.
            if (err.name === "PartialFailureError") {
              console.log("Error Sending Notifications", err);
              return false;
            }
          });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`table.insert: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
      return err;
    }
  }
  // console.log(row);
  insertBigQuery(row);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to return promise or value from you function

```
  async function insertBigQuery(rows) {
    try {
      console.log(row);
      const datasetName = "firestore_export";
      const tableName = "leaseCompany";
      const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery();
      const ds = bigqueryClient.dataset(datasetName);
      const tbl = ds.table(tableName);
      return tbl.insert(rows)
          .then((data) => {
            return true;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            // An API error or partial failure occurred.
            if (err.name === "PartialFailureError") {
              console.log("Error Sending Notifications", err);
              return false;
            }
          });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`table.insert: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
      return err;
    }
  }
```

```
return insertBigQuery(row);
```

Comment: @sankarnatarajan did you notice I made two changes? retrun in the function and return at the end
Also when you say not working what does it mean, do you still get exact same error as before?